# Jquery mobile never reloads first page requested

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, mobile, jquery-mobile, razor

So Im using Jquery mobile with unobtrusive ajax enabled. All URLs are sharing the save Layout-page (that is the same div data-role="page").

My problem is when I load one url eg: /home/events it loads all the correct stuff, but if i browse around the page using the links on the page, every time I get back to /home/events it simply uses the cached version it loaded the first time I arrived at my page.

I ran Firebug so I can see the original page never gets reloaded and Im not sure why. The problem is the same no matter what page is loaded first /home/events, /home/details, /home/someotherpage, as soon as I click a link leading to this URL it simply uses the cached version from when it was first loaded.

Any help is greatly appreciated !

Edit: Problem is not that the server is caching anything, problem is whenever I click a link leading to the first url I requested JQueryMobile refuses to send a new HTTP-Request.

Edit2: Not using rel="external" anywhere beacause i want to use the sweet ass page transitions.

So apparently not a bug, thread discussing it here, ugly-hack solution provided as well:
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/3249

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn off the caching by setting the OutputCache attribute on your action:

```
[OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.None)]
public virtual ActionResult Events()
{
}
```

Comment: As I edited, problem isnt server caching anything, problem is JQuery refuses to send new http-request whenever i click link leading back to the original URL requested